# What typescript type should this JSX code be - React.ReactElement, React.ReactNode, and React.FunctionComponent all fail

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a prop SubmissionComponent and need to assign a type to it.

It expects some sort of JSX - probably a button but more complicated structure possible.

So an example structure:

```
const SubmissionComponent = <p>hi</p>;
```

which is then called with

```
<Submitter 
   SubmissionComponent={SubmissionComponent} />
```

if in my Submitter component I define SubmissionComponent like this

```
SubmissionComponent: React.ReactNode;
```

and I make a

```
<SubmissionComponent/>
```

Then I get the error message where I place the component

```
JSX element type 'SubmissionComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

so ok, how about I change it to

```
 SubmissionComponent: React.FunctionComponent;
```

Then I do not get any error in my code where I have placed the `<SubmissionComponent/>` but I do get an error in my code where I do

```
<Submitter 
       SubmissionComponent={SubmissionComponent} />
```

that error being

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any>'.
```

That implies to me that the type should be ReactElement, if I try

```
 SubmissionComponent: React.ReactElement;
```

Then again I get the error

```
JSX element type 'SubmissionComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

if I try

```
 SubmissionComponent: React.ReactElement<any, any>;
```

I also get the same error

React version is 17.0.2, typescript 4.6.3

Comment: Have you tried doing `<SubmissionComponent/>`

Comment: yes, that is what I meant by the text 
and I make a

<SubmissionComponent/>

in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const SubmissionComponent = <p>hi</p>;` the type of the const is "JSX.Element"

```
const SubmissionComponent = () => (
    <p>hi</p>
);
```

if u make it a function, then u could use it like a "FunctionComponent" and assign it to "React.ReactNode"

Answer (score 2):

The type of `SubmissionComponent` is `JSX.Element` and you should use it in your `Submitter` component with curly braces: `{SubmissionComponent}`.

Example:

```
function Parent() {
  const SubmissionComponent = <p>hi</p>;

  return <Child SubmissionComponent={SubmissionComponent} />
}

type ChildProps = {
  SubmissionComponent: JSX.Element;
}

function Child(props: ChildProps) {
  const { SubmissionComponent } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {SubmissionComponent}
    </>
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCswFcA7DYCeuABRSPpgAoBKOAG8qcOGhYBneAGVaAIxDAJE5vQDCuSPSTc4AXjgAeMAD4AFsEMB6UxWqVRRGLSitDaiwBsAJnFkKlFRYNcBYdGD1Bf0VlVRCtcIBfOCsTKkSqKhgATzAkOA9gHzYcMAl9IRE-eRig9U0w7gAuOAApaQANADoAUU8kEHC7DPs6RhhVAq9vHjBSiRbC4vmBYQcxSXhBaoDY4IbtXWSDOYgyu0ckZ1c4HirRQzT10VEomsC4g6T7o1SqvnSQA)